# Error: Cannot find module 'G:\web_store\my-store\.next\server\app\page_client-reference-manifest.js'

Tags: javascript, typescript, networking, clerk

I am working on my own website at the moment, but i´m having issues with a particular error and I couldnt find any working solution.
Error: Cannot find module 'G:\web_store\my-store.next\server\app\page_client-reference-manifest.js'
Require stack:

- G:\web_store\my-store\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js
- G:\web_store\my-store\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js
- G:\web_store\my-store\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js
- G:\web_store\my-store\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
- G:\web_store\my-store\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\render-server.js
- G:\web_store\my-store\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\processChild.js

I tried all the solutions on the web, but none of them worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.